# Plotting SQL results on graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying plot the results from an SQL query on a graph using Matplotlib but I keep getting the same error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I've tried hardcoding in random values which worked fine, so I believe it's something to to with the format of the SQL results. The result from the SQL query is appended to the variable x_list = [] and returns the list in the format:

```
[(u'Ford',), (u'Vauxhall',), (u'Volvo',)]
```

I then tried to convert x_list into a numpy array with the below code and converts it to the following which still generated the same error:

```
 x_list = np.array(x_list)
 print xlist 

output:
[[u'Ford']
[u'Vauxhall']
[u'Volvo']
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to plot these sql results on the graph without getting this error?

EDIT:

Added how I plot for more information. I am using tkinter to display the graph in my program, tried to replicate it as best I could without all the unnecessary clutter.

```
def plot():
    conn = sqlite3.cursor('Cars.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT model from Cars')
    rs = c.fetchall()

    x_list = []

    x_list.append(rs)
    x_list = np.array(x_list)

    a.plot(x_list)
    canvas.draw()


f = Figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, win)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
```

Comment: How do you plot?

Comment: @user8408080 I've edited the original post to include it

Comment: So you want to plot a list of lists, which have the length one? What should the result look like?

Comment: @user8408080 Is it possible to put the results from the SQL query in single list to plot?

Comment: You would benefit from showing the complete error, not just the last line of it.

Comment: Yes it possible to flatten a list, but what is your expected result?